# When integrating by parts, why does choosing wrong U and V give incorrect answer

Tags: calculus, integration

At school we are learning integration by parts and the teacher told us it is important to know what to use as U and V as sometimes it is not so straightforward. If we chose the wrong ones, the working could be a lot more complicated than necessary. However, in the integral $$2n\int_0^1 x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}dx$$. By letting $u = x^2$ and $v’ = (1-x^2)^{n-1}$ I end up with $[2n\frac{x(1-x^2)^n}{-2xn}]_0^1$ + $2n\int_0^1\frac{ (1-x^2)^n}{n}dx $. Since first part is equal to zero, it ends up as $2n\int_0^1 x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}dx$ = $2\int_0^1(1-x^2)^ndx $

Now using $u = x $ and $v’= x(1-x^2)^{n-1}$ I end up with $[2n\frac{x(1-x^2)^n}{-2n}]_0^1$ + $2n\int_0^1\frac{(1-x^2)^n}{2n}dx$. Since first part equal to zero, it ends up as $2n\int_0^1 x^2(1-x^2)^{n-1}dx$ = $\int_0^1(1-x^2)^ndx$

Now, I know this uses recursive formula and I could’ve approached it better, but that’s not really what I’m stuck on. Why does choosing the U and V as in first case give an incorrect answer. I don’t understand why it’s wrong, sure the second way is faster, much more logical and etc, but what makes it $\mathit wrong$? What assumption has been made/ rule defied. The teacher told us only to do the second way, but didn’t really explain why the first is incorrect. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Integration by parts is "correct" no matter what $u$ and $v$ are, but some choices are "bad" because they may lead to complicated integrals that aren't easier to compute than the original one.

In your case though, you seem to have chosen $v(x) = \frac{(1-x^2)^n}{-2xn}$, but its derivative is not actually $(1-x^2)^{n-1}$. (The $x$ in the denominator cannot be treated as a constant.)